# Variable capture: How variables behave in function closures

Tags: swift, kotlin, functional-programming

I have this code, and I would like to know if the value of the variable `x` is captured by the function at the time it is defined, or if the function captures a reference to the variable itself (or is there something else)?

Would there be a difference in how everything is processed if `x` was a `val`?

```
// Kotlin
var x = 1
fun f(y: Int) = x + y // Function adds 1 to a given Int

x = 2
val y = 3
val z = f(x + y) // Calls f with argument of 5
// z now maps to 7
```

```
// Swift
var x = 1
func f(_ y: Int) -> Int {return x + y} // Function adds 1 to a given Int

x = 2
let y = 3
let z = f(x + y) // Calls f with argument of 5
// z now maps to 7
```

So whenever we call function `f`, we're going to evaluate its body `{ x + y }` in the environment the function was defined. And when we defined this function, we had an environment where `x == 1`.

So function `f` always adds 1 to its argument, no matter where it is called. That is the rule. (This rule is for `let` / `val`, not `var` I assume?)

My question is around the function closure in relation to the `var`.

Just give me a detailed explanation of this (following the scope chain to locate variables in memory), thanks.

Comment: What capturing are you referring to? At least with the Swift code (I don't know Kotlin), there is no capturing in your code. `x` is not `1` when you call `f(x + y)`. `x` is `2` at that point which is why `z` is 7 and not 6.

Comment: At the beginning (let's assume that we have only line 1 and 2) 
line 1 - x maps to 1 
line 2 - f maps to a function that adds 1 to it's arguments 
then later we decide to add line 3 
and now x is 2, and would that change the value of x inside the body? or is still 1 and is going to change when we call the function f later at line 5? 

What I try to understand is how and when the function is getting the new value

Comment: yes, z = f(2 + 3), x is 2
but my question is about how x inside the f body changes (line 2).

Comment: There is no lines 1, 2, or 3 any more. you approved an edit that removed all of your line references. But doesn't running the code answer your question? You know that `x` is 2 when you call `f(x + y)` and the result is 7 so that proves that `x` is 2 and not 1. It's unclear where your confusion is.

Comment: The question is easier to follow after the edit. You were right because x is global and how it is accessed in memory, but I thought x in this case would be accessed differently.

Comment: By the way what also got me confused, is that in swift and kotlin there is no shadowing, where a new binding with the same name as an existing binding is introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both Kotlin and Swift using `var` means the closure captures a *reference* to the variable itself, while `val`/`let`, which are immutable, capture the *value* of the variable at the time of the closure's creation.

Following the example you've given, if you had used val instead you'd be left with the following:

```
val x = 1 
val g = { x + 3 }  // Closure g captures the value 1
x = 2 // this would cause compilation error 

val z = g()    // z will be 4 (1 + 3)
```

Comment: `val` is immutable for a local variable, but not necessarily for a property, where it means read-only and the value can change each time you read it. Something to watch out for here.